# Why Does ExtJS do not Publish the activeItem value in the view model when the active tab is changed via mouse click?

Tags: extjs

```js
var vm = Ext.create('Ext.app.ViewModel', {
    data: {
        active: 'my-tab'
    }
});

var container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    viewModel: vm,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        bind: {
            value: '{active}'
        },
        flex: 1
    }, {
        flex: 3,
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        bind: {
            activeItem: '{active}'
        },
        width: 900,
        title: 'Test',
        listeners:  {
        },
        
        items: [
            {
                id   : 'my-tab',
                title: 'Tab 1',
                html : 'A simple tab</br></br></br></br>'
            },
            {   
                id: 'my-tab-2',
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html : 'Another one</br></br></br></br>'
            }
        ],
    }],
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});

var tab = Ext.getCmp('my-tab');

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text    : 'Select the first tab',
    scope   : this,
    handler : function() {
        debugger;
        vm.set('active', 'my-tab');
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text    : 'Select the second tab',
    scope   : this,
    handler : function() {
        vm.set('active', 'my-tab-2');
    },
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

The code above does these things:

1. It shows a `textfield` whose value config is bound to `'active'` in the view model.
2. It shows a tab panel whose activeTab config is bound to 'active' in the view model.
3. The two buttons tries to change the active tab by updating `'active'` in the vm

My expectation is that when you change the active tab by clicking on the tabs in tab bar, this would also cause the `activeTab` in the view model to update due to binding. At the moment this seems to be not the case.

Any idea on what went wrong here? Is the expectation incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the view model when the active tab changes, you can listen to the tab panel's tabchange event and update the view model's active property when the active tab changes.

```
var container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    viewModel: vm,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        bind: {
            value: '{active}'
        },
        flex: 1
    }, {
        flex: 3,
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        bind: {
            activeItem: '{active}'
        },
        width: 900,
        title: 'Test',
        listeners: {
             tabchange: function (tabPanel, newCard) {
               vm.set('active', newCard.getId());
             }
        },
        items: [
            {
                id   : 'my-tab',
                title: 'Tab 1',
                html : 'A simple tab</br></br></br></br>'
            },
            {   
                id: 'my-tab-2',
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html : 'Another one</br></br></br></br>'
            }
        ],
    }],
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```